# is there a way to have make always perform an action when a Makefile exits?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How can I ensure that make performs an action when the Makefile exits, even if a target rule fails? I'm hoping for something like Perl's END capabilities.

My Makefile needs to do this

- get a signing ticket
- compile code, sign some
- release the signing ticket

So my Makefile looks like this:

```
TICKET=$(shell get-ticket)

all: somerule  anotherrule  lastrule

somerule: 
    compile foo
    sign foo --ticket $(TICKET)

anotherrule: more deps etc
    compile bar

lastrule:
    release --ticket $(TICKET)
```

but lastrule won't do. The problem is that I can't use a final target rule to release the ticket, because if there's an error the rule won't be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use recursion.  Something like this:

```
ifndef TICKET

.DEFAULT:
        @ ticket=`get-ticket` || exit 1; \
          $(MAKE) $@ TICKET="$$ticket"; ret=$$?; \
          release --ticket "$$ticket"; \
          exit $$ret

else

all: somerule anotherrule

  ...etc...

endif
```